# CSS Column Count Load Rows First

Tags: css, grid

Hi I'm kind of new to css and I can't figure out how to load the images horizontally with the following code rather than vertically

```
-moz-column-count: 3;
-webkit-column-count: 3;
column-count: 3;
list-style-type: none;
-webkit-padding-start: 0px;
```

What I get looks like this

[image]

However I'd like it so that the last picture is shown in the second column and then the second to last picture is just kept where it is. In other words I'd like the rows to fill out before the columns do. How can I do this?

Comment: could you create http://jsfiddle.com with your example?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9VJcz/ thank you

Comment: why not just using float left or inline-blocks, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/kBKyg/

Comment: @User577732 - it this issue has been solved, then why don't you close this question?

Comment: how can i close it? there's no answer to accept

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

The HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
</ul>
```

and the css is like this you can change the width of ul element.

```
ul{
    width:100%;
}
ul li{
float:left;
width:30%;    
}
```

tell me is this helpfull